# Magic trackpad gesture recognition

Tags: windows, windows-7, gestures, trackpad

Does somebody know what the easiest way would be to work with the apple magic trackpad and just have it recognize gestures (two-finger up/down swipe and left/right swipe and tap) and not be working as a mouse?
What language / framework should I use?
How can I get the Gestures or the RAW Input data?
I have to do this on Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 already supports gestures via [Windows Touch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543.aspx).

Comment: But does Windows Touch work with the Magic Trackpad? and how can I distinguish between the Magic Trackpad and the inbuild Trackpad?

Comment: It works with Apple's Boot Camp drivers. If you're not using Boot Camp, you can still extract the drivers from the install media and use them on Windows. I have no idea how you distinguish between them. I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to. The point is that you don't need to write any type of software to do this, as the features to interact with gestures are already built into Windows 7. Your reinvented wheel probably won't be very round.

Comment: Oh I already got it working. I want to developt an Aplication, where the magic trackpad is not used as a Mouse, only recognizing certain gestures and controling the windows media player with these gestures. And I don´t really know how to do that. So I´ld be glad about any hints!

Comment: @Adele Did you make any progress with this? Id like to use Magic trackpads mounted on walls as gesture-based light switches for phillips hue and need to get at the raw data from the trackpads.

Answer (score 1):

Apples Magic Trackpad driver for Windows is (from a operating system point of view) a simple mouse driver. You can't capture multi touch gestures from that driver. And you can be sure that you really can't as Apple has no interests to support Windows with real multi-touch. So mission impossible unless you write your own driver (see Linux).

http://www.trackpadmagic.com

Answer (score 1):

All of the Magic Trackpad gestures, such as for 2, 3, 4 fingers can now be enabled in Windows with `Extramagic`, according to ['Extramagic' for Magic Trackpad: 3/4 Finger Gestures & More - Now in Windows!](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1850762).